# How to suppress output of bash command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I've found [this way](https://superuser.com/a/1053577) of checking whether a host is accessible on a given port, however I am only interested in the status code of the command, therefore I am trying something like this:

```
[CptBartender@somewhere ~]$ <dev/tcp/host/port ; echo $?
0
```

This works fine if I try on an open port, however if I check a closed port, I get:

```
[CptBartender@somewhere ~]$ <dev/tcp/host/blocked_port ; echo $?
-bash: connect: Connection refused
-bash: /dev/tcp/host/blocked_port: Connection refused
1
```

Now my next step was to try and discard the outputs of the first command, so I tried:

```
[CptBartender@somewhere ~]$ <dev/tcp/host/blocked_port >/dev/null/ 2>&1; echo $?
-bash: connect: Connection refused
-bash: /dev/tcp/host/blocked_port: Connection refused
1
```

Same output. My questions are, why is the first command printin any output whatsoever and how do I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the *command* that's printing output. You don't have *any* command – the `< /dev/tcp/…` is just regular **input redirection** and is processed by the shell itself.

(And not just that, but redirections are processed left-to-right, so the `<` redirection is processed *before* the `2>&1` one, so it couldn't be redirected *anyway*.)

You can get around this by running the "command" in a subshell. For example:

```
( </dev/tcp/$host/$port ) 2>/dev/null
```

Actually it seems that in this case a subshell isn't required; a command group will work even if it's within the same process – it still forces the "outer" redirections to be processed first:

```
{ </dev/tcp/$host/$port; } 2>/dev/null
```

---

Side note: `/dev/tcp` is a magic path that's handled by bash itself – it doesn't actually exist in Linux's /dev, but can be used with bash redirections. However, this trick won't work with `#!/bin/sh`, and there's still a chance that it won't work with bash on some older systems (which used to disable this feature), or some non-Linux systems.

Comment: Bonus points for explaining that the `</dev/tcp/...` is not a command at all (I wasn't exactly sure what that was... now I know: "do nothing and take this as input... oh wait - it doesn't exist"). Also, it works if I simply change the order so that the error redirect is first. Anyway, thanks!